# How to remove file extension from file name (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a filename variable that contains : `"Filename.csv"` . To extract the filename from a path I use: `Filename=Dir([fStr])` where `fStr` is retrieved from the file that I selected.

I only need the filename without `".csv"`. How do I remove the `".csv"` extension?

Comment: Maybe `Filename = left(Filename, len(Filename) - 4)`.

Answer (score 16):

It's best to use a function like `GetBaseName()` instead of relying on functions to replace text. Windows allows periods to appear within the base filename so something like this is legitimate:

```
My .csv for Bob.csv
```

Using `Replace()` would result in:

```
My  for Bob
```

Not what you're looking for. A better approach would be:

```
Filename = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(fStr)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the replace function:

```
Filename = replace(Dir([fStr]),".csv","")
```

Answer (score 3):

Too late to answer it, might be helpful for future

**Try this**

```
Mid(fileName, 1, InStr(1, fileName, ".") - 1)
```

It will work with any file extension or filename

For example:

fileName : ThisIsMyFile.csv

Comment: It doesn't work if fileName contains more than one dot

Answer (score 2):

My code runs on various systems which may not allow scripting. I rewrote this to get around this limitation.

```
Function FileGetBaseNameNoExt(aFilenameStr As String) As String
  Dim TmpCnt As Integer
  Dim TmpStr As String

  FileGetBaseNameNoExt = aFilenameStr

  If InStr(aFilenameStr, ".") = False Then
    Exit Function
  End If

  TmpCnt = 1
  TmpStr = Left(Right(aFilenameStr, TmpCnt), 1)
  While TmpStr <> "."
    TmpCnt = TmpCnt + 1
    TmpStr = Left(Right(aFilenameStr, TmpCnt), 1)
  Wend

  'Make Sure the Filename is Not Something Odd like .csv
  If TmpCnt < Len(aFilenameStr) Then
    FileGetBaseNameNoExt = Left(aFilenameStr, Len(aFilenameStr) - TmpCnt)
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: It may appear a long code, but I believe it's the most general solution, working for any filename and any Windows settings (i.e. extensions shown or hidden).