# Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I read through a few of the existing VBA questions with this error but I find that the error message is general and there are many, many ways to get it.

My VBA code is below and I am trying to find out why all of a sudden it is not working when it used to. The lines which Excel highlights are between the 2 * which I do not actually have in the code :)

```
Sub publishPDF()

'
' PublishToPDF Macro
' Macro recorded 01/07/2016 by Pczarnota



' Export to PDF

    SaveFolder = "S:\DataOps\InvValidatedFeed\"
    DocName = Range("D1").Value

    *ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=SaveFolder & DocName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False*


    MsgBox ("Another one down!")

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the path contained within `SaveFolder` actually exist? Do you have write permission on that directory?

Answer (score 3):

This must have something to do with the filename in D1, the reliance on the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to define the parent worksheet of D1 or an illegal filename.

```
Sub publishPDF()
' PublishToPDF Macro
' Macro recorded 01/07/2016 by Pczarnota
' Export to PDF
    Dim saveFolder As String, docName As String

    saveFolder = "S:\DataOps\InvValidatedFeed\"   '<~~ access to the share or network drive?
    docName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value  '<~~define the worksheet holding the filename!
    If CBool(InStr(1, docName, Chr(46))) Then 'check for a period (full stop)
        'remove it; the save type will add the appropriate one
        docName = Left(docName, InStr(1, docName, Chr(46)) - 1)
    End If

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=saveFolder & docName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    MsgBox ("Another one down!")

End Sub
```

This works for me but I did not duplicate the network share and used **abc.xls** in Sheet1!D1.

Comment: In the case of silly people who put extra periods in their filenames, perhaps use `InstrRev`? Or this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32025353/293078?

Comment: Excellent point @DougGlancy but what of even sillier people that put periods in their filenames and still rely on the [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) to supply the extension? (e.g. **abc.def** supplied in Sheet1!D1)

Comment: Those people are on their own!